# MEF Silently Stops Finding Exports in Deployment Catalog?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mef, silverlight-toolkit

When my Deployment Catalog contains `System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit.dll` MEF 'breaks'... All I'm doing is adding a reference to this file in my project and the following diagnostics code writes **nothing** to the VS Output Window:

```
this.CompositionContainer.ExportsChanged += (s, args) =>
{
    var o = args.AddedExports;
    o.ToList().ForEach(export =>
        System.Diagnostics.Debug
            .WriteLine("MEF export: " + export.ToString()));
};
```

...when the reference is removed the `ExportsChanged` event fires. Is this problem my "special" problem or can someone else on Earth reproduce this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are subscribing to the [`DownloadCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.deploymentcatalog.downloadcompleted%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) event of the DeploymentCatalog.  In your event handler, check the `Error` property of the EventArgs, and it will probably tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Message = "Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information."

Comment: [outer ex:] Message = "The package downloaded successfully but an error occurred while reading the contents of the package. See the inner exception for more details."

Comment: "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit, Version=4.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The requested assembly version conflicts with what is already bound in the app domain or specified in the manifest. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131053)"

Comment: This article details: http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2010/01/31/mef-and-decrypting-loaderexceptions.aspx